# how to search from two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have one model with name Customer and another model with name contact.

I am saving customer id in contacts table.

In search method I want to search values from contact table as well as customer table.

My method is here:-

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base>

```
 def self.search(search)
  if search
    Customer.joins(:contacts).where("customers.company_name ILIKE? OR customers.status ILIKE? OR customers.types ILIKE? OR contacts.name ILIKE? OR contacts.email ILIKE?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
     end
  end
```

end

This is working but when I start searching if the contact name is not present at that time it is not searching and one more problem is it is displaying same customer two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `includes` instead of `joins`

```
Customer.includes(:contacts).where("customers.company_name ILIKE? OR customers.status ILIKE? OR customers.types ILIKE? OR contacts.name ILIKE? OR contacts.email ILIKE?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```